# Can't find custom GATT service

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my UWP app, am able to discover my Android application running on a device and read its [device name characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.device_name.xml)

It works. But in that same Android application, I have a custom service that I added to the GATT with a read characteristic. I can find my service from another Android app, but can't do it in my UWP app. Here is my code:

```
if (ulong.TryParse(deviceAddress, out ulong address))
{
    BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(address);

    // the name of the device of bluetoothLeDevice matches my device, so I know I have the right address

    var serviceId = new Guid(myCustomServiceId);

    GattDeviceServicesResult result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(serviceId);
    var q = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync();

    if (q?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        foreach (var x in q.Services) // q.Services is empty
        {
            // never comes in here
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have smartphone (iOS or Android) separate from your Android app? If so, use the *nRF Connect* app from Nordic to verify your Android app publishes the services as expected and that you have the correct UUIDs.

Comment: Another tip: use `GetGattServicesAsync` instead of `GetGattServicesForUuidAsync` to enumerate all services and rule out that your UUID/GUID is incorrect.

Comment: I tried using `GetGattServicesAsync` and the only uuid I found was `00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`. I can find it from an iOS device, so it must be something I'm doing wrong in my UWP app.

Comment: I used nRF Connect app to verify that my Android publishes the services as expected, and it does. But I have the connect to it to read my characteristic. Do I need to connect from my UWP app too?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I do need to connect to the device first, because I have to in my Android and iOS implementations. But I can't find anyway to connect, I only see pairing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved it for me, was that instead of trying to find my service/characteristic on a button click callback, I find them in the `myBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received` callback instead:

```
private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    bool isMyDevice = false;

    // figure out if isMyDevice should be true by checking the advertised service uuids

    if (isMyDevice)
    {
        var bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress);

        var serviceId = new Guid(My_Service_UUID);

        var result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(serviceId);

        if (result?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            var service = result.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Uuid == serviceId);

            if (service != null)
            {
                Log?.Invoke("service found!");

                var characteristicId = new Guid(My_Characteristic_UUID);

                var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(characteristicId);

                if (characteristic?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    var c = characteristic.Characteristics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Uuid == characteristicId);

                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        Log?.Invoke("characteristic found");

                        var v = await c.ReadValueAsync();

                        if (v?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                        {
                            var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(v.Value);
                            byte[] input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                            reader.ReadBytes(input);

                            // Utilize the data as needed
                            string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(input);
                            Log?.Invoke(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This tool is also really helpful for anyone else developing with BLE:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE

It let's you read services/characteristics of any nearby BLE device. Can help a lot with testing. The *nRF Connect* app works well too for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the ble capabilities in your Package.appxmanifest?
If you are using visual studio find Package.appxmanifest and double-click it.
go for the tab capabilities and check Bluetooth and save.
You can also use an xml-editor to modify Package.appxmanifest.
Add:

```
<Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
</Capabilities>
```

If you already set the capabilities, have a look at my SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename
on Github: 
https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename
There are no controls to keep it as simple as possible. All the results are shown in the debug output window.

Comment: I did add this capability. One thing I noticed in the example source code is that `GetGattServicesForUuidAsync` is being called in `OnAdvertisementReceivedAsync`. In my code, I'm calling it on button click, so the UI thread...would that be a problem?

Comment: If that was a problem, you would trigger an exception in debug mode.  Using the advertisementwacher has a the great advantage that you know the device is in reach and connectable. If you do it from from a button click You don't know.

Comment: The Android device is placed next to my desktop running the UWP app, but I tried getting my service in my `Received` callback of my `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` and still can't find it. The only other thing that I'm doing differently is that all my BLE related code is in a separate project from my main application; which I don't think would be a problem either..

Comment: Try running my example, it will give you de debug information in the output window for every step, so you know what's  going on. It will take you a few minutes to get it running. Just hit clone or download on Github, unzip the downloaded file, change bleDevicName, MyService_GUID and  MYCharacteristic_GUID in MainPage.xaml.cs, then run the app.

Comment: I tried your app, but couldn't find my services with it. By the way, it will crash on the line `service = services[0];` when there are no services. Also, `eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName` would always be empty for me since I'm advertising a UUID which takes most of the payload.

Comment: I tried running your code again, it now blocks on the line `device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(MyService_GUID)`. I tried changing it to `device.GetGattServicesAsync()` and it still blocks. Any idea why?

Comment: I just added `BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached` as a parameter and it now works. I wonder why though...